# Webservice in android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-services

By SOAP method i want to consume a web service from android/eclipse.But the way of consuming web service is,i have to give an input and it should have to return the proper values from the web service.How to achieve it?

**web method**

```
public class FahrenheitToCelsius {
public double FahrenheitToCelsius(double Fahrenheit)
{
    return ((Fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
}
}
```

**.java class**

```
public class Demo_webserviceActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

       private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
       private static String METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
       private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
       private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";

       Button btnFar;
       EditText txtFar,txtCel;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFar);

       txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFar);
       txtCel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCel);

       btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {

       public void onClick(View v)
       {
         //Initialize soap request + add parameters
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

        //Use this to add parameters
        request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

        //Declare the version of the SOAP request
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        try 
        {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

             //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
             androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

             // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
             SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

             if(result != null)
             {
              //Get the first property and change the label text
               txtCel.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
             }
             else
             {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
         {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
         }
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: please,just a minute i'll upload what i 've done so far

Comment: Please don't go where i need a solution to this. its my request

Comment: please demand me what are the requirements i have to provide u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ?WSDL from your URL and try

> private static String URL =
>   "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";

Comment: Can you tell me why i want to remove ?WSDL

Comment: No..not...i have seen few examples,but on some examples they included ?WSDL.thats why i am asking you

Comment: http://jatin4rise.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/part-2-calling-a-webservice-from-android-application/ please visit this link's source...

Comment: actually i am following this link

Comment: Can you tell me how to write a web method for the web service,which is going to return values in the form of Dataset and Strings.I have googled it so far as per my knowledge but still seeking solution for the method "DATASET"...can you give me any examples